# InternalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Getting internal error when executing this code

```
conn = pymysql.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'abc' )
cursor = conn.cursor()
 query2 = """INSERT INTO paragraphVector (termId, termFreq, kgram) VALUES ((SELECT termId FROM term WHERE term = %s AND kgram = %s), %s, %s)"""

insertDocVec = [(str(term), str(kgram), tf[kgram][term], str(kgram)) for kgram in tf for term in tf[kgram]]
cursor.executemany(query2, insertDocVec)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Probably your select returns more than 1 row and this is the cause of the error message. You may want to change the syntax to `insert ... select ...`

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
INSERT INTO paragraphVector (termId, termFreq, kgram) VALUES ((SELECT termId FROM term WHERE term = %s AND kgram = %s), %s, %s)
```

To this :

```
INSERT INTO paragraphVector (termId, termFreq, kgram) SELECT termId, %s, %s FROM term WHERE term = %s AND kgram = %s
```

and move the last two params to left

Comment: after changing I am getting yet another internal error as:                                    InternalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'lawson'")

Comment: Probably because target column's precision is not enough to hold the given value.

Answer (score 0):

your statement is wrong. Try:

```
INSERT INTO paragraphVector (termId, termFreq, kgram) 

SELECT termId , %s, %s

FROM term WHERE term = %s AND kgram = %s
```